# Openshift 3.11 router failed: "haproxy.go:392] can't scrape HAProxy: .."

Tags: centos-7, ansible, kubernetes

We're trying to install Openshift OKD 3.11 on a CentOS7 server (single host, all-in-one). The installation uses openshift-ansible and all the playbooks complete succesfully. However, even if all the pods (router, registry, web console) were deployed an ran, we're getting this error from the router logs:

"haproxy.go:392] can't scrape HAProxy: dial unix /var/lib/haproxy/run/haproxy.sock: connect: no such file or directory"

That directory was created but the error still appears. The web console isn't accesible in any browser though it was deployed succesfully.

This is my inventory.

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd
nfs

[masters]
openshift.gft

[nfs]
openshift.gft

[etcd]
openshift.gft

[nodes]
openshift.gft openshift_node_group_name='node-config-all-in-one' openshift_node_problem_detector_install=true


[OSEv3:vars]
#openshift_additional_repos=[{'id': 'centos-paas', 'name': 'centos-paas', 'baseurl' :'https://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/openshift-origin311', 'gpgcheck' :'0', 'enabled' :'1'}]
debug_level=4
#ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/keypair.pem
ansible_ssh_user=root
enable_excluders=False
enable_docker_excluder=False
ansible_service_broker_install=False

containerized=True
os_sdn_network_plugin_name='redhat/openshift-ovs-multitenant'
openshift_disable_check=disk_availability,docker_storage,memory_availability,docker_image_availability


deployment_type=origin
openshift_deployment_type=origin

template_service_broker_selector={"region":"infra"}
openshift_metrics_image_version="v3.11"
openshift_logging_image_version="v3.11"
openshift_logging_elasticsearch_proxy_image_version="v1.0.0"
openshift_logging_es_nodeselector={"node-role.kubernetes.io/infra":"true"}
logging_elasticsearch_rollout_override=false
osm_use_cockpit=true
deployment_subtype=registry
openshift_hosted_infra_selector=""


openshift_metrics_install_metrics=True
openshift_logging_install_logging=False

openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_htpasswd_users={'admin': 'admin:$apr1$i/CxP8W/$Oqt4bOOPnGtGlMTH4iQ2a0', 'developer': 'developer:$apr1$dF9cFdOE$Qw5aDt29IwHQlkMEflA/I.'}

openshift_master_htpasswd_file='/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'

openshift_public_hostname=console.openshift.gft
openshift_master_default_subdomain=apps.openshift.gft
openshift_master_api_port=8443
openshift_master_console_port=8443

## Persistent storage, NFS
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_kind=nfs
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_access_modes=['ReadWriteMany']
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_host=openshift.gft
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_nfs_directory=/volume1/SHARED
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_volume_name=registry
```

Comment: ask this question in stackoverflow, there you can put openshift-origin tag

Comment: Hey @Kelper, any progress with this issue? I've the same problem.